# I'm having trouble loading the housing data set from Geron ML chap 2n end to end learning project

Tags: python, machine-learning

Below is my code and error.  Please help me - I'm a Python (and Stackoverflow!) newbie.

```
import os
import tarfile
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd

DOWNLOAD_ROOT = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml/master/"
HOUSING_PATH = os.path.join("datasets", "housing")
HOUSING_URL = DOWNLOAD_ROOT + "datasets/housing/housing.tgz"

def fetch_housing_data(housing_url=HOUSING_URL, housing_path=HOUSING_PATH):
    os.makedirs(housing_path, exist_ok=True)
    tgz_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.tgz")
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(housing_url, tgz_path)
    housing_tgz = tarfile.open(tgz_path)
    housing_tgz.extractall(path=housing_path)
    housing_tgz.close()

fetch_housing_data()
```

Comment: Here's the start of the error messages which I couldn't add to the question---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SSLCertVerificationError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1347             try:
-> 1348                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
   1349                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))

Comment: You *can* add the error message to the question! Please try again.